# Delete points within a given proximity to each other. Not Merge by distance

Tags: geometry-nodes

Basically, I want to find an alternative to *Merge by Distance* node. Current implementation merges not only points but also information that are in these points. For example, in this case normals are also merged, and because of that cones starts tilting at the corners:

[image]

Without *Merge by Distance* cones facing along face normals:

[image]

So is there a way to remove points within a given proximity to each other, without merging its attributes?

Here the test file that you can play with:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can transfer the attribute from the old geometry, the exact logic being arbitrary - here I just transfer from the nearest point:

[image]